# How to speed up browsing application via pywinauto?

Tags: python, winapi, pywinauto

From application that I want to automate I get pane with set of buttons. Clicking on the button adds new buttons set to Pane, and deletes other buttons from source set. Text in buttons are unique in one set, but aren't unique between them. Text on button is the only property I can use to handle it and click, so after clicking, the button is appended to list that contain already clicked buttons. Difference between children of pane and that array are buttons with unique text.

So my function is like:

```
def click_button(textOnButton, clickedButtons):
  children = paneWindow.children() # get buttons currently present
  handles = []
  
  for item in children:
    handles.append((item.handle, item.texts()[0]))
  
  unique_buttons = list(set(handles) - set(clickedButtons)) # remove clicked buttons
  button = [t for t in handles if t[1].startswith(textOnButton)]
  paneWindow.childWindow(handle=button[0][0]).click_input()
  clickedButtons.append((button[0][0], button.[0][1]))


 clickedButtons = []
 click_button("FOO", clickedButtons)
 click_button("IPSUM", clickedButtons)
```

It works correctly, but just one function execution takes.. 2 to 3 seconds what is certainly unacceptable. Most timeconsuming is getting pane children and clicking on button. Anyone has an idea how to speed it up?

It's considerable for me to change tool from pywinauto to something else. Python isn't required.

Comment: First it’s important which backend is used by Application object: backend=“win32” is faster. Also there are some tricks how to choose WindowSpecification keywords to make a search faster. I’m planning to prepare optimization guide with the next major release.

Comment: It doesn’t depend on the tool so much. I heard a feedback that WinAppDriver for Appium is even slower than pywinauto. But I personally didn’t check it yet.